# maven release:prepare gives [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven project which compiles and deploys without any issue. I am trying to use the release:prepare goal but I am getting an error. I have googled and understand that plugins can be given prefixes and the error means it can’t find one with a prefix of ‘C’. I have no idea why it is looking for a plugin with this prefix.

My pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@gitlab.com:rmetcalf9/ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.git</connection>
    <url>ssh://git@gitlab.com:rmetcalf9/ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.git</url>
    <tag>ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA-0.0.1</tag>
  </scm>

  <groupId>metcarob.com.oracledb.sample.schema</groupId>
  <artifactId>ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- 
Command line parameters:
    cmd.env        - the environment this project is to be deployed to (dev/test/prod/etc)
    cmd.parent.sys (OPTIONAL) - for UTILITY schemas this designates the system to use for deployment.
                         this is overridden by the pom property ic.pom.sys if present
 -->

  <properties>
    <ic.ci.deployment.type>OracleDB</ic.ci.deployment.type>
    <ic.ci.resourcedir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</ic.ci.resourcedir>
    <ic.db.ciuser>CIDBADMIN</ic.db.ciuser>
    <ic.db.ciuserpass>PASSWORD_REMOVED_FROM_POST</ic.db.ciuserpass>
    <ic.db.schema.name>SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA</ic.db.schema.name>
    <ic.db.schema.objecttable>schema_objects</ic.db.schema.objecttable>
    <ic.db.sqlplus.connectstring>${ic.db.ciuser}/${ic.db.ciuserpass}@${ic.db.host}:${ic.db.port}/${ic.db.service_name}</ic.db.sqlplus.connectstring>
    <ic.db.jdbc.connectstring>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(enable=broken)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${ic.db.host})(PORT=${ic.db.port})))(CONNECT_DATA=(service_name=${ic.db.service_name})))</ic.db.jdbc.connectstring>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>    

  </properties>

  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>ssh-repository</id>
            <name>ssh-repository</name>
      <url>scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public_snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>ssh-repository</id>
            <name>ssh-repository</name>
      <url>scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>  

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ic_snapshot</id>
      <url>https://mvnsnap.metcarob.com</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>ic_main</id>
      <url>https://mvn.metcarob.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>  


    <build>
        <plugins>       
            <!--  First plugin will caculate the sys property -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.10</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>bsh-property</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>bsh-property</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <properties>
                      <property>ic.actual.sys</property>
                    </properties>
                    <source>
                      ic.actual.sys = project.getProperties().getProperty("ic.pom.sys", session.getUserProperties().getProperty("cmd.parent.sys"));
                    </source>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>     
            <!--  Second plugin will read property values at the start of the validate phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <files>
                    <file>${env.CIICENV_HOME}/${cmd.env}/${ic.actual.sys}.properties</file>
                  </files>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>

              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>deploy-dependancies</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <executable>ci_deployer</executable>
                      <arguments>
                        <argument>${project.basedir}/pom.xml</argument>
                        <argument>NULL</argument>
                        <argument>${cmd.env}</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.actual.sys}</argument>
                      </arguments>
                      <workingDirectory>${ic.ci.resourcedir}</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>


                  <execution>
                    <id>pre-hook</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <executable>sqlplus</executable>
                      <arguments>
                        <argument>${ic.db.sqlplus.connectstring}</argument>
                        <argument>as</argument>
                        <argument>sysdba</argument>
                        <argument>@_control.sql</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.schema.name}</argument>
                      </arguments>
                      <workingDirectory>${ic.ci.resourcedir}/db/pre_migration</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>sqlcodedeploy-setup</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <executable>sqlcodedeploy_setup</executable>
                      <arguments>
                        <argument>${ic.ci.resourcedir}/db/code</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.sqlplus.connectstring}</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.schema.name}</argument>
                        <argument>${project.version}</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.schema.objecttable}</argument>
                      </arguments>
                      <workingDirectory>${ic.ci.resourcedir}/db/code</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>                
                  <execution>
                    <id>migrate-datastructures</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <executable>ci_flyway</executable>
                      <arguments>
                        <argument>"${ic.db.jdbc.connectstring}"</argument>
                        <argument>"${ic.db.ciuser}"</argument>
                        <argument>"${ic.db.ciuserpass}"</argument>
                        <argument>"${ic.db.schema.name}"</argument>
                        <argument>"${ic.ci.resourcedir}/db/migration"</argument>
                      </arguments>
                      <workingDirectory>${ic.ci.resourcedir}</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>deploy-code</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <executable>sqlcodedeploy</executable>
                      <arguments>
                        <argument>${ic.ci.resourcedir}/db/code</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.sqlplus.connectstring}</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.schema.name}</argument>
                        <argument>${project.version}</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.schema.objecttable}</argument>
                      </arguments>
                      <workingDirectory>${ic.ci.resourcedir}/db/code</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>

                  <execution>
                    <id>sqlplusmulti-runtests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <executable>sqlplusmulti</executable>
                      <arguments>
                        <argument>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/db/code</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.sqlplus.connectstring}</argument>
                        <argument>${ic.db.schema.name}</argument>
                        <argument>*.sql</argument>
                      </arguments>
                      <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/db/code</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>                

                </executions>
              </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <extensions>
          <!-- Enabling the use of SSH -->
          <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
             <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
             <version>2.10</version>
          </extension>
        </extensions>        
    </build>  
</project>
```

I use the command mvn -X release:prepare -Dcmd.env=dev -Dcmd.parent.sys=soa to run it and the output is too big for the post but the relevant part is:

```
    INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 43.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\off_desk\eclipse_workspaces\CITesting\ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA\true\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[INFO]                       
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 66.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\off_desk\eclipse_workspaces\CITesting\ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA\true\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 0.890 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-23T12:39:47+01:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/304M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\off_desk\eclipse_workspaces\CITesting\ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA\true), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\off_desk\eclipse_workspaces\CITesting\ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA\true), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:265)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:219)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.663 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-23T12:39:47+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.execute(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:291)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:409)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.AbstractMavenExecutor.executeGoals(AbstractMavenExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:81)
    ... 29 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This has the "No Plugin found for prefix C". 
Does anyone have any suggestions as to where to look to narrow down the cause?

I have tried commenting out all the plugins from the pom and I still get the same error.

Comment: What Maven command did you launch?

Comment: mvn -X release:prepare -Dcmd.env dev -Dcmd.parent.sys soa

Comment: You are missing the `=` when passing your values, maybe this is the issue?

Comment: I think it's a problem with a windows path which starts with `C:`. Because of the `:` maven treats this as plugin coordinates (`<plugin-prefix>:<goal>`). Just an idea, I haven't found the source of the error yet.

Comment: My problem was really silly in my script I had a unwanted space between -Dfile = and the value , just like below 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<space>C:\MyJar.jar
**<space> just to highlight space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was caused by the way I launched maven. I had created a batch script for it in a central batch directory. This worked for

```
mvn package
mvn deploy
etc.
```

but not the release plugin.

I had to put maven in my path. I got another error complaining that maven could not find mvn.bat. I looked in the maven directory

```
C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
```

and I found "mvn" and "mvn.cmd" but no "mvn.bat".
I copied "mvn.cmd" to "mvn.bat" and it now seems to work.

I then found that my arguments were being ignored. I discovered that I need to call mvn in a strange way to make the arguments work:

```
mvn release:prepare -Darguments="-Dcmd.env=dev -Dcmd.parent.sys=soa"
```

Finally it worked. (Well I am debuging a git related issue now)
Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the correct way to pass arguments to the release plugin.
Otherwise release plugin ignores the values of properties.

Or in your pom file, in maven-release-plugin's configuration you should have:
 ${releaseParams}
or
 -Dparam=$value -Dparam=$value